# What happens when Consumer.subscribe(), even there is no broker in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

What happens when you run `Consumer.subscribe()` if there is no broker alive in `Kafka`?

Answer (score 1):

If there's no broker, you should expect a network error because the bootstrap servers defined will not be available

Answer (score 1):

The consumer.subscribe() will try to read the given topic. Since it is requesting a dead broker, the Kafka system will throw a NetworkException.

```
public class NetworkException extends InvalidMetadataException
```

> A misc. network-related IOException occurred when making a request.
>   This could be because the client's metadata is out of date and it is
>   making a request to a node that is now dead.